# ListBox checklist SelectedItem returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to create a Listbox from where it's possible to select elements with checkboxes. It gets the elements through data-binding from a database. The items appear in the Listbox, but when I send the form, the code-behind doesn't receive a SelectedItem value.

The XAML section for the listbox looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="grMozik" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0" DataContext="{Binding}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListBox Name="lbMozik" Margin="15" Width="300" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding MoziNeve}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And for test purposes the code that would show the selected item looks like this:

```
string text = ((ListBoxItem)lbMozik.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(text2);
```

Comment: Create and do post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListBox.SelectedItem` comes from a `ListBoxItem` which has `IsSelected` property set to `true`. If you want to select by CheckBoxes, then bind each of them to owner `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding MoziNeve}"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>
```

Comment: `ListBox.SelectedItem` is not a `ListBoxItem`, it's a data object, except the data object is a `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: @Rekshino, it can be ListBoxItem as well (when Items collection is filled with ListBoxItems)

Comment: As I wrote _"except the data object is a ListBoxItem"_